# student attendance prediction

Tags: predictive-models

Let's say I wanted to be able to predict, from game to game, what the total student attendance would be at an average college football game, where would I even begin?

I would have access to historical attendance figures, would be able to recreate which games were day games and which were night games, would be able to tell you if it was sunny or rainy, which game was homecoming, etc. (all variables that might impact attendance). I'd be able to track percentage increase/decline from one game to the next from any past season.

Where would you take this if you were me?

Answer (score 1):

I would organise the data into the [tidy data format](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html) and load it into a `R`. From here I would check the data is accurate (i.e. mis-entries, odd values, etc.)s. I would then plot the data and try and work out what kind of models would preform best.

If prediction is the goal I would try a suite of models that are fit for the task, but likely beginning with something relatively simple like a generalised linear model with poisson errors. I would check the assumptions and model fit, and perhaps try a few other models depending on what makes sense. These might include things like support vector regression or tree-based models. Alternatively, I might look at time-series models if I thought there was auto-correlation between games, which there likely would be.

I would probably work in a cross-validation framework to assess how accurately my models were at predicting turn-out as well.

Let me know if anything is unclear.